# Grails, querying self-referencing table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a table with a self-referencing field:

```
Class Book{

    Integer id
    String name
    Book version
}
```

When I add books without the "version", the version field is null
now I have to query the Book table for records that don't have version (their version field is null), the following code won't work:

```
def results = Book.withCriteria{
    eq("version", "null")
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Book.id
```

what query should i use?

Comment: btw, that is the error I am getting:
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Book.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`version` is a keyword in GORM used for optimistic locking. Modify your `domain` and the `criteria` as below to make the criteria return appropriate results.

//Domain

```
class Book {
    Integer id
    String name
    Book bookVersion
}
```

//Criteria

```
def book = new Book(name: "test", version: null)
book.id = 1
book.save(flush: true)

def results = Book.withCriteria{
    isNull("bookVersion")
}

assert results && results[0] instanceof Book
```

Also note, `bookVersion` in the question is of type `Book`, it cannot be compared to `String` `null`.